# Install specific PHP version (php 7.1.11) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

The software I want to run requires php 7.1.11, phpmyadmin 4.7.7 and SQLSRV extension. Is there a way to install required packages without having to build them from source? I need a specific 7.1.11 I was only able to get 7.1 or 7.2 from the oerdnj repository
Thanks

Comment: I need a specific 7.1.11 I was only able to get 7.1 or 7.2 from the oerdnj repository

Comment: Are you sure that v7.1.15 (the [current version in Ondřej’s PPA for the v7.1 branch](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=php7.1&field.status_filter=published)) won’t work? The minor revision change suggests that only (important!) security fixes were made since v7.1.11. What exactly did you try, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead?